# How do I create realistic 3D models from photos of people, and places that I can later animate?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, animation, adobe-after-effects

I have an app I have created.

I was having problem with my computer and allowed Microsoft remote access to my computer to fix it. They crashed and later deleted over 200 files including a good portion of my work on my app that I had done for the past two years. I was about to release the beta, demos and had requests for presentations for my app.

Since I now have to redo a huge portion of my work that I had done alone I would like to do some of it as realistic as possible and in 3D. So, I am asking: **does Adobe have a program where I can take my reference photos and turn them into 3D models to use as my characters in my app?**

I have looked at both Photoshop and After Effects so not sure which would be the best starting point.

Comment: Neither app is meant for 3D modeling.

Comment: Hi Sheila, welcome to GD.SE! Could you explain a bit more about your app and what it is supposed to do? Why do you need 3D models? Why do you think modeling in 3D would be faster than rewriting your app? You can [edit] your question to add more details.

Comment: Hi PieBie, thanks for getting back. My game is RPG app that combines music, gaming and social media in a way that is new. It is set in a nightclub. i want a realistic look to the game,  while playing the game there is a dating component. I need the game to look as real/film like within my budget. I just found Adobe's Fuse & Mixamo   I am in the process of learning it now. Any help/guidance is still  appreciated. It is not the rewriting of the code it is redoing of the graphics/art work and timelines that have disappeared

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is such program.The ways to do it are to learn some 3d modeling software and model object from refrence image.Another way is to post job on a site like upwork or freelancer to hire some 3d modeller to make models for you (you need to pay) and another way is to take picture of your model 360 degree and send them to an online site that I fogoten name and software will make 3d model from the pictures.

Comment: Thanks just found Adobe's Fuse and Mixamo learning it now studied Cinema 4D and the other Adobe product but, Fuse is actually dedicated strictly for 3D

Comment: It is possible to automatically reconstruct 3D models from 2D images using [computer stereo vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_stereo_vision).